# Two different widths / sizes of banana plugs on home audio receivers?

Tags: receiver

I am replacing an Onkyo TX-SR606 with an Onkyo TX-NR575. On the TX-SR606 unit, I used these "dual" banana plugs (see photo), a single unit with both positive and negative connections on it. Unfortunately, these "dual" banana plugs don't fit into the terminals on the new TX-NR575. Hence, I have to buy new, single banana plugs that aren't joined together.

Are there two different sizes / widths of "dual" banana plugs? I thought these things were more or less universal.

[image: banana plugs]

Comment: Banana plugs are always singles. Those dual plug bridges follow no standard.

Comment: Typical spacing is 0.75 inch, but that is more of a USA standard, not an international standard. European standards may be based on millimeters instead of mils.

Comment: By the way, all the gold cannot cover the poor quality of the prongs. A "real" banana plug has a rigid tip.

Comment: Thumbs up: https://i.pinimg.com/236x/59/f5/b0/59f5b018a840e9f9a9740e1dd12e0001--bananas-plugs.jpg

Comment: Thumbs down: https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f1/d2/da/f1d2da4a739653e941110d15341b1d2c.jpg

Comment: Or just cut the center insulator with a hacksaw or rotary tool.

Comment: While not a "standard" by definition, most, if not all of the banana plug-equipped professional sound reinforcement amplifiers I have ever encountered here in the U.S. (which is a lot) have a plug spacing that allows use of dual bananas.  De facto standard?

Comment: @Trevor: rather than "width" of connectors you mean "pitch" which implies a distance between centres (as in a chain, for example).

Answer (score 2):

They *are* more or less universal. The conventional pitch in [test equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Probes) is 0.75" or roughly 19 mm, and it looks about right from your image. I just checked all equipment in our lab and everything matches that, from every manufacturer, although I'm sure there are many exceptions. You can buy numerous adapters from and to banana plugs that has the same pitch.

Why Onkyo decided to deviate from this, I don't know. Perhaps the new engineers were not aware of there being a standard. It looks like they have stacked so many outputs horizontally that they *had* to put them further apart vertically so it would be possible to screw them out with the fingers.

[image]